# PowerPoint MasterArt creation

Tags: c#, vsto, powerpoint

I've read the document about the concept, structure of the master art object from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg583880(v=office.14).aspx)
. However, assume that I can create a smart art object (that contains everything like glox file, diagram xml files, etc..). So How can I load it to a specific slide?

I have the following code so far to insert the standard master art object to the slide:

```
 Microsoft.Office.Core.SmartArtLayout artLayout = PowerPointApp.SmartArtLayouts[3];
PowerPointApp.ActivePresentation.Slides[1].Shapes.AddSmartArt(artLayout);
```

But how can I create an art layout from a smart art object file that I've created outside?

```
Microsoft.Office.Core.SmartArt sa = new Microsoft.Office.Core.SmartArt( _external_file_ ); //- invalid assignment

PowerPointApp.ActivePresentation.Slides[1].Shapes.AddSmartArt(sa.Layout);
```

Note: I am using Visual STudio Ultimate 2013, C#, Microsoft PowerPoint 2013, Add-In Express framework

Answer (score 0):

Your custom smartart goes into a file with the .glox extension. Then you may be able to call it by id.

Answer (score 0):

A custom smartart will also appear in the SmartArtLayouts collection so just enumerate through it to get the layout that matches your name.

e.g.
`private Office.SmartArtLayout GetSmartArtLayoutByName(string smartArtName)
        {
            return Application.SmartArtLayouts.Cast<Office.SmartArtLayout>()
                .FirstOrDefault(smartArtLayout =>
                    String.Equals(smartArtLayout.Name, smartArtName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
        }`

The custom smartart will show up in the SmartArtLayouts collection if it is present in the following location: *"%appdata%\Microsoft\Templates\SmartArt Graphics"*.